# Will the temp table be a dynamic one?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have created sql's which mimic an RPGLE program which displays data in work process.
My question is will this code be dynamic and no need for me to do anything, or must this be run constantly?   this creates a *PGM object CLE.

```
 CREATE table RTRINTx(
    PROGR1PST int, PROGR1PUN int, PROGR1TOD int, PROGR1TUN int, PROGR1TOM int, PROGR1MUN int, 
    LASGR1PST int, LASGR1PUN int, LASGR1TOD int, LASGR1TUN int, LASGR1TOM int, LASGR1MUN int, 
    PCKGR1PST int, PCKGR1PUN int, PCKGR1TOD int, PCKGR1TUN int, PCKGR1TOM int, PCKGR1MUN int, 
    ASSGR1PST int, ASSGR1PUN int, ASSGR1TOD int, ASSGR1TUN int, ASSGR1TOM int, ASSGR1MUN int, 
    SHPGR1PST int, SHPGR1PUN int, SHPGR1TOD int, SHPGR1TUN int, SHPGR1TOM int, SHPGR1MUN int, 
    HLDGR1PST int, HLDGR1PUN int, HLDGR1TOD int, HLDGR1TUN int, HLDGR1TOM int, HLDGR1MUN int);    

-- Engraving Processing
-- Count for Previous Day
Insert into RTRINTx(PROGR1PST)
SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')  
AND OHORDT IN('RTR','INT','SAM') 
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'));

-- Quantity Total Previous Day
update RTRINTx set PROGR1PUN = 
(select COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')  
AND OHORDT IN('RTR','INT','SAM')  
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'  
AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' 
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')));

-- Count for Today
Update RTRINTx set PROGR1TOD = 
(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')  
AND OHORDT IN('RTR','INT','SAM') 
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')));

-- Quantity Total Previous Day
Update RTRINTx set PROGR1TUN =
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')
AND OHORDT IN('RTR','INT','SAM')
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')
AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' 
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')));

-- Count for Tomorrow
Update RTRINTx set PROGR1TOM=
(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')  
AND OHORDT IN('RTR','INT','SAM') 
AND OHREQD =cast(Right(Replace(Char(current date + 1 day, ISO), '-', ''),8)as int) 
AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')));

-- Quantity Total Tomorrow
Update RTRINTx set PROGR1MUN =
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')
AND OHORDT IN('RTR','INT','SAM')
AND OHREQD=cast(Right(Replace(Char(current date + 1 day, ISO), '-', ''),8)as int) 
AND OHHLDC = ' '
AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')));
```

Comment: When I see comments like "Count for Previous Day", it sounds like the data should be in a permanent table, not a temporary one.

Comment: because this is dynamic the data changes throughout the day.

Comment: this data will be displayed in a crystal report so it the cr needs to run this stored proc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those statements are static.  They will have to be executed periodically in order to keep the data up to date.

If you want dynamic updates you could convert those statements into a single [view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzhcview.htm) that will recalculate simply by being accessed.

Comment: James, I was thinking about a trigger. would  that work?

Comment: @Adams A trigger could be used but is over-complicated for this simple query.  A view is much easier to construct and more appropriate in this case.

Comment: we were thinking view would be also over complicated because actually we have many more sql's this is only one quearter of them.

Comment: @Adams Try to think in different terms.  Currently, you create a temporary work file, load data into that work file and print a report from that work file.  What you want to do is envision running the report directly from the source data.  A view is a very good way to dynamically reformat the source data so Crystal can consume it.

Comment: the view is fine but how do i use all the sql's statements with UNION ALL?

Comment: don't think we can create 1 view for all our SQL - 1 reason is that we don't have a primary key to join these files as this SQL statements

Comment: There are so many issues with what you're trying to do here. Let's start with the result table you define at the top.  Is it truly necessary to put each of these various result fields each in separate columns of a single row?  Perhaps some design with one statistic per row, with a code indicating what it was about, might make more sense. That type of design might be easier to understand, possibly simpler to produce, debug, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use is MQT (Materialized Query Tables).

```
CREATE TABLE INVTOTALS AS                              
(WITH TEMP AS (SELECT DEC(SUM(QTY),7,0) as TOTAL,      
PART FROM INVDETL                                      
 GROUP BY PART)                                        
SELECT INVMAST.PART, DESC, PRICE, COST, TOTAL FROM INVMAST 
 LEFT JOIN TEMP ON INVMAST.PART = TEMP.PART)           
 DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED                               
 REFRESH DEFERRED    
 ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION                                  
 MAINTAINED BY USER
```

To refresh this table all you need to do in your program is

```
REFRESH TABLE INVTOTALS
```

- See more at:
  [link 1](http://www.mcpressonline.com/tips-techniques/sql/partner-techtip-creating-sql-materialized-queries.html)
  [link 2](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/partnerworld/pub/pdf/courses/438a.pdf)